# Error while adding Pushe cordova plugin to Intel® XDK project

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, pushe

While adding cordova plugin of Pushe library to my android app which was built by Intel® XDK, I saw the attached error.

Please help me on this.

[image: Pushe stacktrace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Intel XDK does not support gradle-based build yet.

Pushe plugin for cordova contains a file named *build-extras.gradle*.

You can delete this file from the plugin (before adding it to your project) and then go ahead and add the plugin.